# Select single item from a list

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ what is the best way to select a single item from a list if the item may not exists in the list?

I have come up with two solutions, neither of which I like.  I use a where clause to select the list of items (which I know will only be one), I can then check the count and make a Single call on this list if count is one, the other choice is to use a foreach and just break after getting the item.

Neither of these seem like a good approach, is there a better way?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `IEnumerable.First()` or `IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault()`.

The difference is that `First()` will throw if no element is found (or if no element matches the conditions, if you use the conditions).  `FirstOrDefault()` will return `default(T)` (`null` if it's a reference type).

Comment: So simple, not sure how I missed it.  Thanks.

Comment: it actually confuses, when we have a List of item and we want one item from it based on a condition(Where()), method name is First/FirstOrDefault, documentation said - Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements. What comes to mind is that, this method will get the first item in that list without iterate through the list. [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @KuganKumar It has to iterate until it finds a match (or hits the end and doesn't find one) - it's the "first matching element", not "first element of collection"

Answer (score 21):

Use the FirstOrDefault selector.

```
var list = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

var firstEven = list.FirstOrDefault(n => n % 2 == 0);

if (firstEven == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("no even number");
else 
    Console.WriteLine("first even number is {0}", firstEven);
```

**Just pass in a predicate to the [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) or [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method** and it'll happily go round' the list and picks the first match for you.

If there isn't a match, FirstOrDefault will returns the default value of whatever datatype the list items is.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 15):

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();

items.Find(p => p == "blah");
```

or

```
items.Find(p => p.Contains("b"));
```

but this allows you to define what you are looking for via a match predicate...

I guess if you are talking linqToSql then:

example looking for Account...

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();

Account item = dc.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == 5);
```

If you need to make sure that there is only 1 item (throws exception when more than 1)

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();

Account item = dc.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == 5);
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but usually calling `.SingleOrDefault()` is the way to go to return either the single element in the list, or a default value (null for reference or nullable types) if the list is empty. 
It generates an exception if the list contains more than one element.

Use `FirstOrDefault()` to cover the case where you could have more than one.

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete the answer, If you are using the LINQ syntax, you can just wrap it since it returns an IEnumerable:

```
(from int x in intList
 where x > 5
 select x * 2).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy ways, depending on if you want to deal with exceptions or get a default value.

You can use the `First<T>()` or the `FirstOrDefault<T>()` extension method to get the first result or `default(T)`.

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4 };
var result = list.Where(i => i == 3).First(); // throws InvalidOperationException
var result = list.Where(i => i == 3).FirstOrDefault(); // = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`SingleOrDefault()` is what you need

cheers

Answer (score 0):

just saw this now, if you are working with a list of object you can try this

```
 public class user
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

  List<user> userlist = new List<user>();

        userlist.Add(new user { username = "macbruno", password = "1234" });
        userlist.Add(new user { username = "james", password = "5678" });
        string myusername = "james";
        string mypassword = "23432";

  user theUser = userlist.Find(
            delegate (user thisuser)
            {
                return thisuser.username== myusername && thisuser.password == mypassword;
            }
            );

            if (theUser != null)
            {
               Dosomething();
            }
            else
            {
                DoSomethingElse();

            }
```